# graphic LCD with the greatest ease_of_use:cost ratio

Tags: lcd

I'm looking for a (graphic) LCD to get started with. It doesn't need to be color. It doesn't need to be serial (but it should at least be multiplexed so I don't have to connect wires to each individual row/column). I don't care about the resolution as long as it's greater than about 40 pixels in both dimensions. Size should be > 1".

It *must* be straightforward to use, have plenty of documentation (preferably even example code, but not necessary), and be easy to connect to (with <30 I/O lines. <18 would be great). And of course, I'd prefer something inexpensive ($20 max) ;-)

Feel free to list more than one LCD per post. Try to include resolution, size, I/O lines and approximate cost. Bonus points if you provide a link to a supplier ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

128 x 64, buckets of support information, 9 wires. US$15.25.

http://www.adafruit.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=37&products_id=250

Comment: Yes, this tutorial is quite informative: http://www.ladyada.net/learn/lcd/st7565.html

Answer (score 3):

The LCDs from low end Nokia phones might fit the bill.

http://www.sparkfun.com/commerce/product_info.php?products_id=569

$15

128x128 pixels

4096 colours

Comment: Yup, this is what I thought of as well.  A little small at 1.2" square, but the rest of it specs out just right.

Comment: This one doesn't look like it's easy to connect to. From what I see, you need a special connector (which SparkFun supplies), and then the leads on the connector are pitched at 0.5mm.

Answer (score 0):

Nokia 5110 LCDs can be found on ebay for less than $4 each in single quantity. Plenty of documentation available. I have used them with MSP430, PIC and AVR.